# FaceBook payment integration can not

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, payment

I'm doing facebook integration. 
Stuck on payment. 
fb.canvas.pay want to use. 
I want to sell this way 
could not figure out how to do it. 
code can not be directly when applying. 
I think og: I have something I need. 
How do I process payment? 
samples can be sent or Have someone to help? 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Facebook payment for what? Your Unity game?

Comment: yes, 
unity was done with my game.

Comment: I have a hard time deciding whether to flag this question as unclear, too broad or off-topic, it fits every category. Please add more details and describe your problem as best as you can. If you want debugging help you'll have to post your code and the specifics of the issue you've run into.

Comment: I'm going to do on facebook payment transactions 
I'm using the Unity 3D engine. 
fb.canvas.pay When using the method I get the error. 
Error code: 1383133 
How do I process payment?

Comment: It's include the relevant codes in your question. Otherwise, it's hard for the community to help you figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the most likely reason you receive an Error code: 1383133 is if the game that opens the payment dialog doesn't have payout information, a name or a company associated with it.

Look at your Unity game's app ID and check for company names, company association etc and fill in that information. The error should disappear once you've filled everything in.

Comment: Thank you for your response .
but I 've created companies .
on the page of the application developer , I pressed the button canvas payment .
I press create a new company .
I created a company .
payout at the following writes.
" You must be an admin to view the payout of both the app and the company to report . "
the problem does not end .